# Amazon Product Advertising API ItemSearchRequest

Tags: c#, amazon-product-api

I am using Amazon's Product Advertising API to search for products and it works out well. I get results I need. However, when I search for "Bishoujo Catwomen", instead of getting records whose title contains (Bishoujo && Catwomen), it does a (Bishoujo || Catwomen) and hands me the results.

This is my code:

```
ItemSearchRequest request = new ItemSearchRequest();                    
request.SearchIndex = "All";
request.Keywords = "Bishoujo Catwomen";
```

I want my SearchIndex to be All and I only need titles whose name has both Bishoujo and Catwomen. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You may find what you need in the reference [here](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01/DG/PowerSearchSyntax.html) in the Amazon API Docs.

It's called the Power Search Syntax and does describe how to handle booleans in addition to categorized searches.  I don't consider the documentation extremly clear, but it should help you with this.

Comment: Thanks nycdan. But it doesn't work, atleast not when we have "request.SearchIndex = "All";"